# JSON parser for C++ under Windows CE

Tags: json, windows-ce, jsoncpp

Do you know any JSON parser that can be used for development in C++ for Windows CE?
As I understood [json-cpp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsoncpp/) is not compilable for WinCE. Please correct me or prompt any alternative.

Comment: what about this: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/177114/which-library-is-used-to-parse-JSON-on-C-WinCE

Answer (score 1):

Use [Poco C++](http://pocoproject.org/)'s module [Poco::JSON](http://pocoproject.org/docs-1.5.4/Poco.JSON.html). It's compilable on WinCE ([WinCE Platform Notes](http://pocoproject.org/docs-1.5.4/99200-WinCEPlatformNotes.html))